# All the libraries must use the same versions

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

My depencies

```
dependencies {
compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+'

}
```

I get an error in `appcompat` line when compiling that found version `27.1.1,26.1.0`  examples include ..`vectordrawable 27.1.1` nd `supportdesign 26.1.0`

> My target SDK is 26.
>
> I tried to switch versions to 27 but my SDK target is 26, I get an error.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you see this type of problem, explicitly declare the probelmatic libraries in your gradle file with the same version of your other support libs:

```
implementation "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0"
implementation "com.android.support:design:26.1.0"
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
```

This happens because some of your dependencies use a different version of it.

Also, use implementation not compile. Compile has been deprecated:

```
implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'
```

Comment: I added the lines get now vector-drawable 27.1.1 , design 26.1.0

Comment: I have only 1 drawable line with 26.1.0 I don't know where it is getting the 27.1.1 from

Comment: Let me see, 1 sec

Comment: There's also implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'

Answer (score 0):

There are conflicted dependencies in your project. You need to check up the dependencies tree of your project by running the following command in your Linux terminal:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

or if you're using Windows:

```
 gradlew app:dependencies
```

in your root project. Where app is your module name.

Quick checking your dependencies block, you will find the following library:

```
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+'
```

is using support library version 27.1.1 for its dependencies (You can check [its build.gradle](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/blob/master/build.gradle)).

You can exclude the library from image cropper with:

```
implementation ('com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0') {    
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
```

The side effect of using the old version of support library is you can't be so sure that your program will work correctly. It's because the owner of library probably didn't test the library with older version of support library.

The better way is by changing your `BuildToolsVersion`, `compileSdkVersion`, `targetSdkVersion`, and `support libraries` to version **27**. Something like the following:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 27
  buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.package.name"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27

    ...
  }

  ...
}

dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

  // your other dependencies
  ...
}
```