# Updating External Libraries in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm fairly new to Android development, so apologies if this is obvious. I've searched quite a lot but am unable to resolve my issue.

In my build.gradle file I have the following section:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.2.2'
}
```

However the line `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'` is showing with a red squiggly line underneath and displaying the following message:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 26.1.0, 25.3.1. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0 and com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1 less... (⌘F1)
>
> There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).

I am unable to find out how to solve this issue. Building the project works fine and does not report any errors. I've tried doing `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart` but to no avail.

After doing a bit of searching I read that I can add `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'` to the build.gradle file and it should fix it, however the same error shows even after syncing.

This is an old project I made sometime last year and it doesn't have a lot in it, but I thought it would be better to learn how to resolve this issue rather than just creating a new project to get around it.

Comment: checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50183315/7765139

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

`implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0'`

Comment: Thanks, this gets rid of the squiggle. Do you know why it is that without this line it will default to using v25.3.1 for the support version?

Comment: Probably 'animated-vector-drawable' support library is compiled with v25.3.1 of support. By adding this line, we are -kind of- forcing it to use the most recent version we are using.

Answer (score 0):

Although in your question, error is explaining everything, `com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0` and `com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1` are not having same version.

Should always keep support libraries version same in `build.grdale`.

```
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_lib_version"
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation "com.android.support:design:$support_lib_version"
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$support_lib_version"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$support_lib_version"
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$support_lib_version"
```

where `support_lib_version` is a constant.

```
ext {  support_lib_version = '26.1.0'}
```

in same `build.gradle` file out side 'android' and 'dependencies'.

Comment: But my build.grade file does not contain any reference to anything running version 25.3.1, so I am confused as to where this error comes from.

Comment: According to a [recent Google blogpost](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html) using a constant to set the version is now an anti-pattern.