# Android Firebase Connection - Gradle Error

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I tried to setup my Android Studio for a firebase connection. I followed the instruction and this is where i am right now:

[build Gradle Project File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/banXz.png)

[build Gradle Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qL8S1.png)

[Message when i hover other the red underlined implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ht0t.png)

So what i did is -> add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` and
`compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'` into the module file and `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0`' in the project file. And now i see the red underlined line, how can i fix it?

Here is the Code from the build.gradle (Module: App):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ozan.firebasetest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle (Project: FireBaseTest2):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: I think this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50183287/all-the-libraries-must-use-the-same-versions/50183315#50183315

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All the libraries must use the same versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50183287/all-the-libraries-must-use-the-same-versions)

Comment: Please don't link to images of code.  It's better to copy the code and error messages into the question so it's easier to read and search.

Comment: I included the code.

Comment: Did i understand it right ... i have to include the examples in the error message manually with the same version as  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'?

Comment: @O.T update google services too, this will help you avoid further errors in future and always make sure keep up with latest version of dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Just change compile with implementation and it will work!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the latest version **(4.0.1)** of google-services based on [this link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin). This could help avoid further errors.

build.grandle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ozan.firebasetest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```